# Travis.ci missing perlbrew perl's releases installed before 'perlbrew use'

Tags: perl, travis-ci

In accordance with http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/perl/ we should just declare on `travis.yml` what version we want to test against, and it will use that `perl` version.

But if you look at https://travis-ci.org/eokoe/Iota/jobs/78738472 you could see that the first thing (after declare `ENVs`) is that `travis.ci` is doing an `"perlbrew use $perl-version"`

When I did an `perlbrew available`, it shows that none perl version is installed (when is installed, there's a `'i'` before the name)

Is this a bug, or should I do an install (takes `"a little"` long to compile perl, wasting energy!) and then `perlbrew use` again?

Comment: Have you actually installed 5.16.3 using perlbrew? Follow this [tutorial](http://blog.fox.geek.nz/2010/09/installing-multiple-perls-with.html) to properly setup perlbrew.

Answer (score 1):

`perlbrew use x` will only work if you've previously used `perlbrew` to install a `perl` as `x`.

Sure it takes time (unless you want to risk skipping the tests), but how do you expect to test against a build of `perl` you haven't installed?